# Dynamic Facebook Open Graph Meta tags - How add prefix to <Head> tag?

Tags: asp.net, facebook

I am using DotNetNuke content management system and am creating a custom module for it. I want to dynamically generate and write out the open graph meta tags to the `<head>` section. That part I can accomplish, but now I need to add the "prefix" portion of the `<head>` tag, i.e. to look like this:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns# YOUR_NAMESPACE: http://ogp.me/ns/apps/YOUR_NAMESPACE#">
```

How do you programmatically do this?

Comment: Got it: Page.Header.Attributes.Add("prefix", "og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# thedynoroom: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/thedynoroom#")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it: Page.Header.Attributes.Add("prefix", "og: ogp.me/ns# fb: ogp.me/ns/fb# thedynoroom: ogp.me/ns/fb/thedynoroom#";)